# Website function that creates folders and files with a click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I had this idea to make a website that creates folders and files that I can specify the name of with inputs. I have powershell done til that point that I can create a folder but I cannot specify the name with inputs in html.

The question is if it is any "function" in powershell that is more like `getElementByID()` from js?

This is the code I have:

```
<body>
    <form>
          <input type="text" id="folderName" placeholder="Folder name">
          <input type="submit" name="" onclick="createFolder" value="Create">
    </form>
    <script>
           function createFolder {
               mk dir getElementById('folderName')
           }
    </script>
</body>
```

I am completely new to powershell and would like some help!

Comment: What exactly would a powershell `getElementByID` do?

Comment: If i have a input in my html where I can specify what name the folder should have

Comment: *in your HTLM*? What HTML? What does powershell (a windows scripting language) have to do with HTML? Are you reading a file?

Comment: I have a HTML file with two inputs. One text and one submit. The input have a id as folderName and the submit calls in the powershell function.

Comment: *I had this idea to make a website that creates folders and files* that implies your giving a web page write access to your disk, this is a bad idea and will likely expose a security issue

Comment: I want to have the powershell to do: mk dir getElementById(folderName)

Comment: The website is only staying on my localhost

Comment: How are you calling powershell from HTML? Is this just on your computer? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Comment: I mean ignoring how unclear this question is, what is the point of a HTML page on your local machine that creaates folders? That sounds like a [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine)

Comment: This is the code I have atm: 


<body>
   <form>
                  <input type="text" id="folderName" placeholder="Folder name">
                  <input type="submit" name="" onclick="createFolder" value="Create">
            </form>

<script>
                  function createFolder {
                        mk dir getElementById('folderName')
                  }
            </script>
</body>

Comment: And I want to be able to specify what name the folder should have within HTML

Comment: That code won't work.... at all....... your obviously totally mis understand what a script tag does (it runs javascript) and what powershell is

Comment: Maybe I can't. I am completely new to powershell I just looked it up and it made sence in my head. but I guess not

Comment: Do you mind help me getting a understanding of what I could do?

Comment: OK, **You can't run powershell** from client side javascript. In fact you can't create folders on your machine using any web page scripting language. What your trying to do makes no sense. There isn't really anymore to say on this

Comment: Oh. So I am not able to make a folder on my local system within a website?

Comment: Well screw that idea then xD